# angular - bindings fire off observable

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, rxjs

My expectation is that when I setup an observable like this, any bindings will use the result of the `switchMap` call:

```
this.thing = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
        switchMap(async (params: ParamMap) => {
            const id = +params.get('id');
            const data = await this.thingService.getThingDetails(id);
            return new ThingDisplay(data);
        })
    )
```

However, if I have multiple bindings in the form of `{{ (thing | async)?.prop }}` i see that the service method is called *for each of the bindings*.

This implies that each `| async` usage is creating an independent subscription to the `this.thing` Observable.

How can I avoid this? I'm seeing angular templates where I can specify some context using `let-*` syntax.... but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way than specifying an entire template dedicated to this.... the last time I used MVVM it was knockoutjs so there was definitely a context binding you could use.... is there something similar in angular? I have had no luck finding anything so any advice would be appreciated.

I'm primarily wondering

- Should I be binding to an Observable in my component?
- Should I use my Observable subscription to set an instance variable? That feels odd to me...
- Why is `| async` causing the Observable to fire *every single time*?
- Where can I find legitimately good documentation around this? There seems to be some stuff covered in angular docs and some stuff covered in rxjs docs... there are blog posts for every version of angular in existence that are maybe out of date (with methods I can't find like `getValue`)... is there a definitive source for *anything* in angular (at least in regards to observables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here. First Observables are multicast. That means that for each subscriber the function in the switchMap gets a called.

There are a couple of possible solutions. One is to subscribe to `this.thing` and use a non observable version of the value in your template. Doing this you get rid of your async pipes and need to clean up your observable when the component is destroyed. Or, you can turn the observable into a Subject (Subjects are unicast) and still use the async pipe in your template.

Comment: I went this direction..... I was trying to fit rxjs `Observables` into a `Promises` + `Generators` + knockoutJS Observables box and it doesn't quite fit